# Excel: How to find the last empty Cell

Tags: excel, find

In Excel, does anyone know how to look Upward from a given row to find the last blank Cell?

I've got a strangely formatted excel export that I'm trying to report out of. However, i'm stuck trying to find an efficient formula to find the data.

Here are 2 examples of the exported format of this report. For each "Item Number" it's listing all the parts it's used in. This might be just one SKU, or 15 SKUs, or none. So this causes sub-header area to not be a consistent size. Each new Item number gets this same format. I've got 8000+ Item numbers, each output this same format.

here is the array formula:

```
{=INDEX($B$1:$B$70600,SMALL(IF("Item Number:"=$A$1:$A$70600,ROW($A$1:$A$70600)-ROW($A$1)+1),COUNTIF(INDIRECT("$A1:$A"&ROW()),"Item Number:")))}
```

My formula basically looks for the SKU (i.e. 35376) and reports back the above Item number it uses (i.e. 02859). It does this by finding the row number of the SKU, and then counting the number of strings "Item number:" from the top to current row, and reports the last one.

**

```
Created By:     Employee                    
Create Time:    01/08/2015 04:16:16 PM CST                      
    Where Used Report                       
Item Number:    02859                       
Description:    Packaging 35376                     
Level   Subclass    Number  Rev Description Find Num    Qty BOM Notes   
.. 2    SKU 45268   A        MCO-01101  Product Name    0   1       

Created By:     Employee                    
Create Time:    01/08/2015 04:16:16 PM CST                      
    Where Used Report                       
Item Number:    02858                       
Description:    Packaging 35345                     
Level   Subclass    Number  Rev Description Find Num    Qty BOM Notes
.. 2    SKU 35376   E        ECO-07812  Product name    0   1   
.. 2    SKU 39022   A        MCO-01198  Product Name    0   1   
.. 2    SKU 39033   A        MCO-01187  Product Name    0   1
```

**

However, my current function is crashing out as i've got 70k rows it's searching through.

What I'd rather do, is simply look *UPWARDS* in the sheet to find the row number of the last header value (i.e. "Number") or even just the last empty cell. Instead, it seems that most of the functions are geared around looking down to the next value. Which forces me to look from the Top to the current row.

Anyone know how to look Up from a given row to find the last blank Cell?

Comment: Perhaps another way to ask this is, How to count the number cells between current row and a given cell above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LOOKUP` in various ways to get the **last** occurrence of some value, e.g. this formula in row 100 will find the last instance of "Item Number:" in column A above and return the corresponding value from column B

`=LOOKUP(2,1/(A$1:A99="Item Number:"),B$1:B99)`

This can be fast if you know how many rows you need to look at, e.g. if the previous "Item number" will always be within 30 rows you can set the range in the formula to look at only 30 rows

Comment: Thans, this got me started where i needed to go. I made some slight modifications to limit the lookup range by adding an Indirect add Row()-50 in there (for both the the column A and B portions).  i.e. INDIRECT("$A$"&IF(SUM(ROW()-50)<1,1,SUM(ROW()-50))&":A"&K70597) (the K column being simple row() to give the current row. I wasn't able to get ":A"&Row() to work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using SUMPRODUCT, but s it searches all 10xxxxx cells in a column, don't have too many, else the spreadsheet will slow to a crawl.

```
=INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A:A="Item Number:")*ROW(A:A))))
```

This will return the data in column B where the last "Item Number:" appears